# User generated/edited content with admin acceptance and history schema

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I am building a system, e.g. a movie database, which stores data about movies in the database. Let's say the base look like this:

```
movies
- id
- title
- description
- premiere date
```

I would like users to be able to add new movies, but also edit individual fields in existing movies. The changes would have to be displayed in the Administrator Panel, where the administrator can accept the appropriate changes.

So far I have come up with this approach.

A table with user changes that has exactly the same schema as the movies table:

```
movies_user_changes
- id
- author_id
- movie_id
- title
- description
- premiere date
- accepted
```

If user adds a movie, fill in all fields. If only changes the description, add a record with only the description column filled. When the administrator accepts the change, set `accepted` to 1, and if it change not new movie make a copy of the changed record to `movies_edit_history`, then UPDATE record with `id = movie_id`.

I also thought about making a key-value table.

```
movies_user_changes
- id
- user_id
- movie_id
- key
- value
- accepted
```

When user change a description, add a record with `key - description` and value. When user add few changes, add a few records. However, I don't know what to do when the user wants to add a new movie to the database. Add it to the movies table with the field `accepted = 0`? This approach does not seem ideal.

And as for history of edits, I want to store it for easy show of edit history, and revert changes if needed. I wonder if the `movies_edit_history` table should contain a new record for each change, or it would be better if it had one record for one movie, but each field contained JSON with an array of changes e.g.

```
{
  [
    'edit_id': 1,
    'user_id': 1,
    'value': 'description_edit',
  ]
}
```

The movie database will contain about 40-60 thousand records, and the system will contain about 5-15 thousand (maybe more in the future), regularly adding and suggesting changes user, so the database of changes may grow quite quickly.

How should I approach this problem? Has anyone created a working system like this and could advise me on how to plan it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the main issue here is not really the structure of your data or the database model itself, but rather how to effectively manage the flood of changes coming in to the system on a regular basis.

I'd suggest looking at how Wikipedia does this, or some other large-scale projects of this kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Editing

Some other ideas which may help:

1. Flag each row in the database as "new entry" or "edited" for easy recgonition and classification
2. Use some visual indicators like colors in the UI, that will help
3. Make sure there's enough staff to handle accepting the changes or new entries, this may be the actual bottleneck
4. What if several users edit the same entry at the same time?

- Rob changed the title
- Eve changed title and description
- Mike changed description and premiere date

You want to accept Eve's title change, but Mike's premiere date change. In this case, it would be better to have all changes listed as separate, so you can quickly approve / delete these which you want.

In other words - dont' store global edits per user (per movie), but rather individual changes of each column values, for example list them like this:

- movie_id
- timestamp_of_submitted_change
- who_edited
- field_name_changed <- title, description, premiere, etc
- new_field_value
- if_accepted
- timestamp_accepted

Perhaps some of the above ideas will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the reason for to have 2 tables.

Think about the next structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                     title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                     description TEXT,
                     premiere DATE NOT NULL,
                     createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                     createdBy INT, /* foreign key to users table */
                     state ENUM('not approved', 'approved', 'declined') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not approved');
```

When the row for some movie is created the first time, the user fills all columns except `createdAt` which is set automatically and `state` which is assigned to `'not approved'` (of course these columns are not shown in user interface).

When the row for some movie is edited a copy of current (some current - this may be "last approved" or "the most last" or even "the most last from approved plus non-approved created by me") row for this movie is created, the status of newly inserted row is set to `'not approved'`, and user edits that copy.

Administrator checks new row and alters its `state` with `'approved'` or `'declined'`.

When the rows are retrieved the latter (by `createdAt`) row with status set to `'approved'` is displayed.

Some service event procedure executed, for example, daily, may exist. It deletes declined rows and not approved rows which are old enough (for example, a month).

Of course the structure may vary. For example you may do not create `state` column but add `approvedAt` column and make `createdAt` nullable. If a row has NULL in `approvedAt` then it is not aproved yet. If a row has NULL in `createdAt` this means that the row was declined, and it must be deleted by service event procedure.